# Why error Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using this to trim the data to the left of pipe sign, means I only want data to the left of pipe sign else whole if no pipe sign is there but it throws error.

Error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Code:

```
      SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
          ,case
        when CHARINDEX('|', ProjectNo) > 0 then
            rtrim(left(ProjectNo, CHARINDEX('(', ProjectNo) - 1))
        else
            ProjectNo
      end ProjectNo
```

Comment: btw add an `end` at the end for `case..when` syntax.

Comment: yeah I have but stills ame proiblem

Comment: `ProjectNo` is of numeric type ..? That might be the problem, looks like you needed to convert to a string.

Comment: no, its string sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append the character you are looking for in the `CHARINDEX()` expression:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID],
       RTRIM(LEFT(ProjectNo, CHARINDEX('|', ProjectNo + '|') - 1)) as  ProjectNo
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `CHARINDEX('(', ProjectNo) - 1` might give negative value which is invalid, as error states.
I belive you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
,case when CHARINDEX('|', ProjectNo) > 0 then
        rtrim(left(ProjectNo, CHARINDEX('|', ProjectNo) - 1))
      else ProjectNo
 end ProjectNo
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
          ,case
        when CHARINDEX('|', ProjectNo) > 0 then
             rtrim(left(ProjectNo, CHARINDEX('|', ProjectNo) - 1))
        else
            ProjectNo
      end ProjectNo
```

you are getting '|' not '('

or

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
              ,case
            when CHARINDEX('(', ProjectNo) > 0 then
                 rtrim(left(ProjectNo, CHARINDEX('(', ProjectNo) - 1))
            else
                ProjectNo
          end ProjectNo
```